# Filter plugin without data-attribute

Tags: sorting, jquery-plugins, filter, custom-data-attribute

How to filter or sort info without data-attribute by plugin of `MixItUp/Isototpe`?

Maybe filter will be an #url and sort will be class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a JSON set, you can filter against the values like so (I'm also assuming you have taken the filter/sort value from the DOM already):

Haven't run this so apologies if not exact - and I'm not used to stack overflow formatting yet but any issues and I'll edit. I think the logic should be OK

```
var dataset = [
    {url: '/test'},
    {url: '/test2'}
];

var filterValue = '/test2'; // pass this to function or get from DOM
var sortBy = 'url'; // again, pass in somewhere or get from DOM
var sortType = 'asc';

function filter(data, filter) {

    var filteredResults = data.filter(function (el) {

        return (filter !== '' && el.url.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase())) !== -1;

    })  

    return filteredResults;

}


function sort(data, sortBy, sortType) {

    var sortIndex = sortType === "asc" ? 1 : -1;


    data.sort(function (a, b) {

        if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) {
            return -1 * sortIndex;
        } else if (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) {
            return 1 * sortIndex;
        }

        return 0;

    })
}   

var filteredResults = filter(dataset, filterValue);

sort(dataset, sortBy, sortType); //dataset will be sorted
```